# CMake question: Two same output obj generated by VS IDE and CMake command line cause LNK4006

Tags: cmake

I am new for CMake, and I'm adding NASM files into projects by CMakelists.
With this version, IDE and project have two output folders to generate same obj, so that cause warning lnk4006 already defined second definition ignored.
One output folder and it is like build\encoder\x86.
Another is like  build\encoder\x86\xxxenc_x86_asm.dir\Debug\ or build\encoder\x86\xxxenc_x86_asm.dir\Release.

I have trid to update the second output path to be same with the first, but it can't work.
CMakelists like following：

```
add_library(${ENCODER_X86_ASM_LIB_NAME} OBJECT "")

if ((LINUX OR MACOSX OR WIN32) AND ${ENABLE_ASM})
  set(ASM_EXECUTABLE "${NASM_EXE}")

  if(CMAKE_GENERATOR STREQUAL "Xcode")
    add_library(${ENCODER_NATIVE_ASM_LIB_NAME} INTERFACE)
  endif()
     
  set(X86_ASM_SRCS
      asm/avx2/average_avx2.asm)

  if (WIN32)
    set(ASM_FLAGS ...)
  elseif(MACOSX)
    set(ASM_FLAGS -I${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ -f macho64 -O2 -DARCH_X86_64=1 -DPREFIX -DOS_MAC=1 -DPIC -Worphan-labels -DSTACK_ALIGNMENT=16)
  elseif(LINUX)
    set(ASM_FLAGS -I${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ -f elf64 -O2 -DARCH_X86_64=1 -DOS_MAC=0 -DPIC -Worphan-labels -DSTACK_ALIGNMENT=16)
  endif()

  #generate objects when building CMake

  if(CMAKE_GENERATOR STREQUAL "Xcode")
    asm_compile_to_target(${ENCODER_NATIVE_ASM_LIB_NAME} ${X86_ASM_SRCS})
  else()
    asm_compile_to_target(${ENCODER_X86_ASM_LIB_NAME} ${X86_ASM_SRCS})
  endif()

  if ((MACOSX AND (CMAKE_GENERATOR STREQUAL "Xcode")) OR WIN32)
    foreach(asm_file ${X86_ASM_SRCS})
      set(ASM_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${asm_file})
      get_filename_component(filename "${asm_file}" NAME_WE)
      set(ASM_OBJ "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${filename}${CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION}") 
      list(APPEND ASM_SRCS ${ASM_SRC})
      list(APPEND ASM_OBJS ${ASM_OBJ})
      add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${ASM_OBJ}
        COMMAND ${ASM_EXECUTABLE}
        ARGS ${ASM_FLAGS}  ${ASM_SRC} -o ${ASM_OBJ}
        DEPENDS ${ASM_SRC}
      )
    endforeach()
  
    foreach(OBJ ${ASM_OBJS})
      list(APPEND ASM_PRIMITIVES ${OBJ})
    endforeach()
  
    foreach(SRC ${X86_ASM_SRCS})
      list(APPEND ASM_PRIMITIVES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${SRC})
    endforeach()
  
    source_group(Assembly FILES ${ASM_PRIMITIVES})
  
    if(CMAKE_GENERATOR STREQUAL "Xcode")
      target_sources(${ENCODER_NATIVE_ASM_LIB_NAME} INTERFACE ${ASM_PRIMITIVES})
    else()
      target_sources(${ENCODER_X86_ASM_LIB_NAME} PRIVATE ${ASM_PRIMITIVES})
    endif()
  
    if (MACOSX)
      add_custom_target(${ENCODER_X86_ASM_LIB_NAME}-asm ALL DEPENDS ${ASM_PRIMITIVES})
      target_sources(${ENCODER_X86_ASM_LIB_NAME} INTERFACE ${ASM_PRIMITIVES})
      add_dependencies(${ENCODER_X86_ASM_LIB_NAME} ${ENCODER_X86_ASM_LIB_NAME}-asm)
    else()
      target_sources(${ENCODER_X86_ASM_LIB_NAME} PRIVATE ${ASM_PRIMITIVES})
    endif()
  endif() ## if ((MACOSX) AND (CMAKE_GENERATOR STREQUAL "Xcode") OR WIN32)
endif() ## if ((LINUX OR MACOSX OR WIN32) AND ${ENABLE_AVX2})

target_compile_definitions(${ENCODER_X86_ASM_LIB_NAME} PUBLIC)
```

Here, CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR is one output folder and it is  build\encoder\x86.
how to deal with this issue?
Background is this: we need to support incremental compiling in IDE, also need to support building by cmake command line.

I have tried to update output path(or directory) as:

```
set_target_properties(${ENCODER_X86_ASM_LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PATH} )
set_target_properties(${ENCODER_X86_ASM_LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES BUILD_RPATH ${PATH} )
set_target_properties(${ENCODER_X86_ASM_LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH ${PATH} )
set_target_properties(${ENCODER_X86_ASM_LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PATH} )
```

It just can't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Anybody familiar with CMake? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: If hard code $(IntDir) inside VS， to be build\encoder\x86 , same with CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR , it can work, but how to update CMake

Comment: what is `asm_compile_to_target`? in particular, does it "compile to target" during configure stage (i.e. when you run CMake), or during the build stage (i.e. during actual build)?